# Generic Kendo MVC Grid Used with Different Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use a Kendo Grid generically as a partial view.  Kendo requires either a type defined or a datatable to instantiate the grid in a razor view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<object>() or @(Html.Kendo().Grid(dataTable)
```

My issue is i want to use the Grid for whatever object, not a specific one.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<object>()
    .Name(Model.MetricName)
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 15, 20, 50 }))
    .ColumnMenu()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action(Model.MetricName, "AdHocReport", new { metricId = Model.MetricId }))
    )

)
```

by using Object i am able to dynamically load the data returned from the ajax .read method.  However the issue is with dates.  They are returned in JSON format.

Ive tried this method and I still get JSON string representation of the date

[Kendo ASP.NET MVC helper Grid generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096465/kendo-asp-net-mvc-helper-grid-generic-class)

Is there a way to define the type of grid from a string representation of the type?  So lets say i have a string property on the viewModel that is the type of the grid. How can i say  Grid ?

ive tried using reflection to instantiate the type but i get the infamous "you are using a variable like a type"

This is driving me nuts... any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm afraid the kendo grid and it's MVC wrappers aren't designed for that. You'd have to do something like [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/binding-to-datatable-0191a594e359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the way to make this work and bind correctly and as mentioned above my mrmashal it has to do with using dataTables.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GridTable)
```

here is the viewModel property

```
public DataTable GridTable { get; set; }
```

To make this dynamic i use reflection to define the dataTable based upon the properties of a the class i want to populate the grid with

```
Type elementType = Type.GetType(className, true);
var properties = elementType.GetProperties();

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
    }
viewModel.GridTable = dataTable;
```

However, the key is making sure that the data returned from the AJAX read was a dataTable, not an `IEnumerable` type.

```
DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable<AssetLocationHistoryMetricData>(metricData);

var result = dataTable.ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

and this is what i used to convert the List to a dataTable

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```